# Eclipse autocomplete for JSTL, JSP

Tags: eclipse, jsp, autocomplete, jstl

I'm using Eclipse, making a dynamic web project and have included JSTL in my JSPs. Everything works fine, I have core autocomplete available and so on.

The problem is as follows: when I `foreach` with JSTL a specific array list of custom objects, I can't access properties of an instance. Here's an example:

```
<c:forEach var="person" items="${listOfPeople}">
    <c:out value="${person.name}" />
</c:forEach>
```

So, a `person` has a property `getName()`. If I use scriplets e.g.:

```
<% 
   Person p = new Person();
   p.getName(); 
%>
```

Eclipse enables autocomplete on object `p`, but when I use JSTL, there is no autocomplete on instance.

Is it something missing or wrong with my Eclipse, or is it meant to work without autocomplete?

Comment: Can you add the code where you create the variable listOfPeople and the class Person, if possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no autocomplete on EL expressions. EL expressions are just strings that get evaluated when the JSP is executed (they remain as strings when the JSP is transformed to a Servlet).

Code like: `<c:out value="${person.name}" />` gets translated to something like this (pseudocode):

```
COutTag tag = new COutTag();
tag.setPageContext(pageContext);
tag.setValue(ExpressionEvaluator.evaluate("${person.name}"));
tag.doStartTag();
// ... etc
```

The server will evaluate the expression and return the value to the tag.

If you are on an JSP 1.x version you might get something like this (preudocode):

```
COutTag tag = new COutTag();
tag.setPageContext(pageContext);
tag.setValue("${person.name}");
tag.doStartTag();
// ... etc
```

and the tag itself [calls his own evaluator to get a value](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/el/core/OutTag.java#OutTag.evaluateExpressions%28%29) from the expression.

At runtime the `person` key is searched in page scope, if not found there it is searched in request scope then session scope etc until it's found. Then whatever is found must have a `getName` method and that's called etc.

A JSP is normally used as a view and somewhere you have the `person` object created and placed in scope and the flow is forwarded to the JSP. How is your IDE supposed to know at design time what you will have in each scope at runtime? It doesn't know so there is no autocomplete.

If you instead do `<% Person p = new Person(); p.getName(); %>` then that's a scriptlet containing Java code and your IDE knows is a `Person` class and can examine it and know the properties and methods so for that you have autocompletion, but for EL expression there isn't, they are just strings.